# How to add fa awesome icon to bootstrap button

Tags: html, css

I was trying to add all possible ways but without luck, this code is bit to hard for me, could any body help me.

How to add `glyphicon glyphicon-search` to `<input style="width:10px" type="submit" class="btn btn-nomest" onclick="$('input:not(:submit,:button), select',this.form).val('');"`

If I make another span its not working

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

Comment: You're asking about FontAwesome, but your are adding classes for Bootstraps include Glyphicons, which are different. Do you have the Glyphicon fonts?

Comment: Yes I have, I add bootstrap to site and also attached Glyphicon script

Comment: Thank you, I add bootstrapt script and everthing is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<button>` instead of `<input type="submit">`

```
<button 
  style="width:10px"
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-nomest"
  onclick="$('input:not(:submit,:button), select',this.form).val('');">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
</button>
```